# citation style in latex for Partial Differential Equations in Applied Mathematics journals

Tags: bibliographies

Here is my code

`main.tex` file

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1.}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=small}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{orcidlink}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \small    
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1
}
\newcommand*{\mei}{\textcolor{orange}}
\newcommand*{\corr}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand*{\mannaf}{\textcolor{purple}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
%author section
\title{\LARGE \textbf{ ** }
\author[1,2]{Md.** \orcidlink{**}}
\author[1]{Rajandra Chadra Bhowmik}
\author[1]{** \orcidlink{**}} 
\author[1]{M** \orcidlink{**}}
\author[1]{U\orcidlink{**}}
\author[3]{M\orcidlink{**}}
\affil[1]{Department of Mathematics  }
\affil[2]{Department of Mathematics }
\affil[3]{Department  }
\date{}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% \renewcommand{\theequation}{%
%     \ifnum\value{subsection}=0 \thesection.\arabic{equation} 
%     \else \thesubsection.\arabic{equation}
%     \fi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\begin{abstract}
In the 

\end{abstract}
\keywords{the }
\section{Introduction}
~\citep{islam2021searching}, the  $(G' /G)$  method~\citep{zhang2010improved},  extende~\citep{elwakil2002modified},  
    

% \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

%   \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

`sample.bib` file

```
@article{islam2021searching,
  title={Searching closed form analytic solutions to some nonlinear fractional wave equations},
  author={Islam, Md Tarikul and Islam, Md Ekramul and Akbar, M Ali},
  journal={Arab Journal of Basic and Applied Sciences},
  volume={28},
  number={1},
  pages={64--72},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
  doi = {10.1080/25765299.2021.1886678}
}


@article{zhang2010improved,
  title={An improved (G'\/ G)-expansion method for solving nonlinear evolution equations},
  author={Zhang, Jiao and Jiang, Fengli and Zhao, Xiaoying},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Mathematics},
  volume={87},
  number={8},
  pages={1716--1725},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis},
doi = {10.1080/00207160802450166}
}

@article{elwakil2002modified,
  title={Modified extended tanh-function method for solving nonlinear partial differential equations},
  author={Elwakil, Sayed A and El-Labany, SK and Zahran, MA and Sabry, Refaat},
  journal={Physics Letters A},
  volume={299},
  number={2-3},
  pages={179--188},
  year={2002},
  publisher={Elsevier},
doi = {10.1016/S0375-9601(02)00669-2}
}
```

output references looks like :
[image: output of latex file]

**but I want to specific style like**
For example,
in [3], "Sayed A Elwakil, SK El-Labany, MA Zahran, and Refaat Sabry." should be "Elwakil SA, El-Labany SK, Zahran MA, Sabry R.",
and
"Physics Letters A, 299(2-3):179–188, 2002." should be "*Phys Lett A*. 2002;299(2-3):179–188.".
especially I want to this type of references link :
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.padiff.2021.100220
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.padiff.2021.100220

**required style**

> Author1,Author2. Article title. Journal name. Year; Volume(Issue):Page, and DOI

Comment: What is the question? Edit: when you post code in the future, please make sure the question is visible, sometimes the code blocks don't end properly and the question part is interpreted to be code :)

Comment: I want to "Author1, Author2. Article title. Journal name. Year; Volume(Issue):Page, and DOI" style references. how can I do it?